# how can call this class and function in other pages in c#

Tags: function, class

i want call this function in other pages. but idont know

```
public class registering_class_file
    {
    public KeyValuePair<Literal, Literal> settingfunc1(Literal lit_pub_adver_barcap1, Literal lit_div_adver_start1)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<Literal, Literal>(lit_pub_adver_barcap1, lit_div_adver_start1);}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you my answer is:

```
Literal lit_pub_adver_barcap1 = new Literal();
        Literal lit_div_adver_start1 = new Literal();
        registering_class_file ss = new registering_class_file();
        KeyValuePair<Literal, Literal> newValue = ss.settingfunc1(lit_pub_adver_barcap1, lit_div_adver_start1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend that you include your class in a name space like this:

```
    namespace NameA 
    {
       public class registering_class_file
       {
          public KeyValuePair<Literal, Literal> settingfunc1(Literal lit_pub_adver_barcap1, Literal lit_div_adver_start1)
         {
            return new KeyValuePair<Literal, Literal>(lit_pub_adver_barcap1, lit_div_adver_start1);
         }
      }
 }
```

Then you may use this in another file with a using clause:

```
using NameA;
namespace NameB
{
   public class B
   {
       private registering_class_file regClass; // references NameA.registering_class_file
...
       private KeyValuePair<Literal, Literal> register(Literal key, Literal value) 
       {
          return regClass.settingfunc1(key, value);
       }
    }
}
```